# CDT does not find Cygwin gcc include files correctly, even after stating include paths

Tags: cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have a rather embarrasing question, as this problem was no issue on a linux machine and on my Windows XP machine. But now, after having finally switched to Windows 7 64bit, I ran into the basic problem of making Eclipse find my C++ include files...

**My setting:**
I am running Windows 7 64bit. I have installed cygwin to "C:\Program Files\cygwin" and Eclipse Juno 64bit to "C:\Program Files\eclipse".

**My problem:**
I created a basic "Hello World" C++ Makefile project with Cygwin toolchain. Compilation works without problems, but Eclipse still complains that it cannot find the include to "iostream".

**What I tried:**
In Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes, I set the Include directory for GNU C and GNU C++ to

```
C:\Program Files\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include
```

which contains the iostream include in a subdirectory. **This didn't work**

Then I tried the exact directory

```
C:\Program Files\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include\C++
```

containing iostream. This time, the include was found, but even after rebuilding the index, Eclipse still coulnd't resolve std, cout and endl. Then I tried the include directory of the 3.x version of gcc

```
C:\Program Files\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\3.4.4\include\C++
```

and it worked. Unfortunately, I require the 4.x version of gcc, so this is no permanent solution for me.

**My Question:**
How I can I resolve this problem and make Eclipse find the gcc 4.x include directories and use them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing your project-specific changes, you have to make Eclipse 'forget' and re-discover your compiler's include directories. Do this via  **Windows | Preferences | C/C++ | Build | Settings** ; you need to clear the 'Discovery' entries for gcc.

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16259616/1593077).